# Laravel eloquent: relationship between two owner of a table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have three tables **Students**, **Courses** and **Grades**.

and grade has two foreign keys: **student_id** and **course_id** and it's belong to two table.

```
class Grade extends Model
{
    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
    }
    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
    }
}
```

also, student and course have many grades:

```
class Student extends Model
{
    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Grade');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Grade');
    }
}
```

Now, I want to make a relationship between student and course, for example for student1 I want to retrieve all courses that have a grade on it. something like this but it's not correct:

```
$student1->grades->course
```

I can simply write

```
@foreach($student1->grades as $grade)
      $grade->course
@endforeach
```

but I don't want it, I want to have `($courses as $course)` in my foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you need to refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through link to achieve this,

Add **hasManyThrough** relation in student modal.

```
public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Course',
            'App\Grade',
            'course_id', // Foreign key on Grade table...
            'id', // Foreign key on Course table...
            'id', // Local key on Student table...
            'student_id' // Local key on Grade table...
        );
    }
```

I'm not tested this code but, this is the way

Answer (score 2):

What about making grades table a **PIVOT TABLE** for a many-to-many relationship between students and courses.

```
class Student
{
    // an alternative name could be gradedCourses.
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'grades');
    }
}
```

So you are able to access the course directly from this relationship.

```
@foreach($student->courses course)
      $course->name
@endforeach
```